# Summarize Multidimensional Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, object, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find the best (quickest) way to summarize a multidimensional array which will then get passed into an object.

For example if I have `object[,] Data` that contains data similar to:

```
John,Utah,Huntsville,0120152,60
John,Utah,Huntsville,06122013,40
Dallin,Maryland,CityTown,10202012,30
Aaron,Connecticut, Harbourville,12122017,100
Dallin,Maryland,CityTown,04232011,8
Aaron,Virginia,GeorgeTown,02212013,200
```

This will get passed into an object which would be defined something like the following:

```
string name, string state, string city, List<int> date, List<double> total
```

So a representation of the data could look something like:

```
Dallin,Maryland,CityTown

                         04232011, 8
                         10202012, 30                          

John,Utah,Huntsville,

                    0120152, 60
                    06122013,40
```

I know I could fetch the distinct items from each Column then use a For and if statments, but being new to programming and having an extremely large dataset I am a bit worried about how long it will take. And being a multidimensional array also makes it difficult to sort. So any on how to approach this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Dont worry about premature optimization, optimize later. What is the number of records on avg?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to have the data in a multidimensional array?  What if, for example, you structured the data as follows:

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ActivityDate { get; get; }
    public double ActivityTotal { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public List<Activity> { get; set; }
}
```

Data entry into this type of structure should be relatively easy, and then you would have the added benefit of simple sorting, summarization, etc via LINQ.

When you say "large" dataset...  how large is large?

EDIT:

Fair enough...  I didn't realize you didn't control how the data was loaded into your object.

That said, maybe the Domain object would look simply like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public List<int> Date { get; set; }
    public List<double> Total { get; set; }
}
```

And this is an EXTREMELY rough example of how you could convert your `Data` object into this class.  Note this has absolutely nothing in the way of error trapping or type validation:

```
List<Person> p = new List<Person>();

for (int i = 0; i < Data.Length; i++)
{
    p.Add(new Person()
    {
        Name = (string)Data[i, 0],
        State = (string)Data[i, 1],
        City = (string)Data[i, 2],
        Date = (List<int>)Data[i, 3],
        Total = (List<double>)Data[i, 4]
    });
}
```

Comment: The data set comes to me as a multidimensional array so not much i can do about that, so my goal is to take it from that Array and pass it into an object like you have listed above, so I could definitely use something like the classes you mention above, but the trick is getting it from the Array into those classes, and i'm looking at a few million lines.  Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using LINQ (This is actually one line of code :-) )

```
var results = File.ReadAllLines(@"Your file path.txt")
        .Select(record => record.Split(','))
        .Select(tokens => new { Name1 = tokens[0], Name2 = tokens[1], Name3 = tokens[2], Group1 = tokens[3], Group2 = tokens[4] })
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name1, x.Name2, x.Name3 }).ToList();            

        foreach(var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Key.Name1);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Key.Name2);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Key.Name3);                

            foreach(var groupItem in result.ToList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(groupItem.Group1);
                Console.WriteLine(groupItem.Group2);
            }
        }
```

The values would be grouped according to this requirement.

> Dallin,Maryland,CityTown
>
> ```
>                      04232011, 8
>                      10202012, 30
> ```
>
> John,Utah,Huntsville,
>
> ```
>                 0120152, 60
>                 06122013,40
> ```